# Show image from Firebase with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-storage

I want to see the link to my image in the `imageUrl` variable.

When I log `sampleImage`, I see JSON-like data and I can see a link in this data's i section.

But when I log `imageUrl`, it returns `undefined`.

```
render() {
    const uid = '12345';     
    const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref(uid).child(uid);
    const sampleImage = imageRef.getDownloadURL().then();
    const imageUrl = sampleImage.i;
    console.log(sampleImage);    
    console.log(imageUrl);
    return (
        <View>
            <Image style={{ width: 55, height: 55 }} source={{ uri: null }} />
         </View>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting an image is a network request so it takes a little while. If you want to log the image (and you don't use async/await) then you have to do it inside the .then()

```
const sampleImage = imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(result => console.log(result));
```

Rather than doing all of this in the render method, do it when the component mounts and store the URL in state. That way you can just reference the state object in your render method.

Comment: Hello! Yes you are amazing, finally i can see my link in log but now problem is i can't set it to a variable for image uri.

Comment: Use state. Set state inside the then and then reference state in your image src.